# Inspircd startup issue with modes on startup

Tags: irc, inspircd

After upgrade my Inspircd instance from 1.1 to 2.0.5 r0. I am getting the following output in the inspircd log file:

```
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode s called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode o called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode i called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode w called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode v called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode o called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode b called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode l called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode k called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode i called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode n called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode t called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode m called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode p called while still registered
Sun Nov 24 04:26:47 2013: ERROR: Destructor for mode s called while still registered
```

I have tried to `apt-get uninstall inspircd` without any luck. What can I do to resolve this issue?

UPDATE:
I have also tried `apt-get purge inspircd` and reinstalled. I still get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

The 2.0.5 is ancient, please try the latest release (2.0.14 as we speak) from github and compile yourself if your distribution doesn't include current binaries.

Comment: I have solved it. I compiled from source. I purged the version from `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this is the first link in google so here is how i solved the issue:

```
service inspircd reload
```